# capturing a dialog box's process

Tags: c#, windows, shell-extensions

I'm working on a shell extension in C# where I need to monitor if the system has thrown up a dialog box for moving/copying/deleting files.  When the system throws up a box, I need to start running a process for as long as that box is active.

I know that SetWindowsHook exists in C++, but my knowledge in that arena is pretty limited right now.  Is there something similar in C#?

Comment: you can pinvoke any Win32 function you feel is nessescary

Comment: @Boo - never done that before...

Comment: can you elaborate on the overall problem you're trying to solve? It sounds like you broke your problem into multiple impossible (or at least impossible while not engaging in unsupported behavior) steps and are asking about just one of the impossible steps. Maybe there is a better way to break down the problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen - I'm writing a copyhook extension using EZShellExtensions.  I have a need for a message box to pop up in front of the copying dialog, but the copy dialog always seems to take precedence

Comment: There is no supported way of hooking into the copy dialog to display another message on top. (Indeed, there are so many people trying to interfere with file copying that there's a special flag that says "disable copy hooks for this operation"). And undocumented technique is likely to break with the redesigned dialog in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't pinveked before then have a look at [setwindowshookex (user32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowshookex). I am not sure what message you need to hook to get notified on copy/move/delete etc. But at least this should solve your pinvoke problem.

Comment: I'll take a look and report back as soon as I read that link in-depth.